# What is the default timezone for nestjs cron (@Cron) decorator

Tags: node.js, cron, nestjs, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I am writing a cron to run at midnight every day in Indian Standard Time.

```
@Injectable()
export class CronService {

  @Cron("0 0 * * *")
  async midnightCron() {
    // implementation
  }

}
```

My instance is deployed in `AWS Mumbai region`.

I want to know if the @Cron decorator uses local time or UTC time for execution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cron` package](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron) that NestJS uses just works based on the `TZ` environment variable if no timezone is passed to it when scheduling the task. This is a default environment variable that *usually* reflects the system's clock, but can be set to `UTC` to have Node's `Date` class function as if it were always in UTC time.